# Static class/methods in multithreaded app

Tags: c#, multithreading, static

I have multithreaded application that needs an access to MSSQL. I have created a class with static methods where each method looks like this:

```
public static int [] Login(string [] LoginDetails)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
}
```

Is that correct? I am not experienced in multithreading but I guess each thread will run "copy" of this static method with its variables and so they will not be shared. I assume if I declared static members (like sqlConnection) on the class level and made it static, it would be shared and thus it would cause concurrent access issues.

Comment: "And thus" what? The variable `connection` above will be local to each method run, that's correct.

Comment: In my opinion this method does not need to be static. Just don't worry about threads in this case because the database engine is designed ground-up to handle and optimize concurrency and will handle multiple connections and everything for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that it "copies" the method itself, but each method invocation (whether in the same thread recursively or different threads) will indeed get its own separate set of local variables.

So long as none of the data here is shared between threads in a mutable way, you should be fine.

(As an aside, it's more idiomatic to include the array part of a type alongside the name, with no spaces - so `int[]` instead of `int []`.)